# if stament with uint8_t

Tags: if-statement, uint8t

> knowing the value of the variable tempStatusSelectorByte is 0, in the if stament it is giving true for tempStatusSelectorByte>4.

```
uint8_t tempStatusSelectorByte;

tempStatusSelectorByte = AT24C32_Device.readStatusSelectorByte();
printf("settingup -> statusSelectorByte: %d\n", statusSelectorByte); //It prints 0

if(tempStatusSelectorByte>4 ){ // it is true
```

Please let me know how to solve the problem.

Comment: You're printing `statusSelectorByte` but you're checking `tempStatusSelectorByte`.

Comment: Conclusion: choose proper and distinctive names for your variables.